# IIS8 Reverse Proxy - Custom external port

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, reverse-proxy, iis-8, ports, iis-arr

I am trying to configure my IIS reverse proxy to route http connections to an internal server however I am not sure how to achieve what I need or even if it is possible.

I have a sub domain on my IIS server for example,

testing.contoso.com and externally I would like to have http://testing.contoso.com:8080 which will then map to my internal server http://server04.contoso.local:8080. So I do not want my internal site to appear as http://testing.contoso.com on port 80.

My reason for doing this is that I will have quite a few internal and external corresponding ports.

Is it possible to configure this with my IIS reverse proxy or does IIS only support ports 80 & 443 externally?

Thanks in advance, Neil

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your question, it should be fairly easy to make that work using IIS Application Request Routing: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

That should let you use any ports or hostnames in a machine being exposed and then let that route to any other machines (or same) in any ports or combination. It also will allow you to offload cache of static files, and many other nice features. It uses URL Rewrite for the main engine on which server to route to, so you can literally add any logic you want, and if need be you could use extensibility of URL Rewrite to add custom code to define the logic (though the built-in configuration one should be rich enough).